# cannot upload images to DRF using React Native

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload image from react native to django server I cannot upload it.
i can get uri of image properly at the server end following error is occur

```
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'Services_image' at row 1")
```

my server end code

```
class ServicesList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,JSONParser,FileUploadParser)


    def post(self, request,):
        data=request.data
        print(data)
        Services.objects.create(s_name=data.get('title'),description=data.get('description'),
                                provider_user_id=self.request.user.id,
                                services_rate_per_hour=70,Services_image=data.get('image'))
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

models.py

```
 Services_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='Services', blank=True,null=True)
```

my uri of image

```
 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540m.arshad5857%252FManagPatients/ImagePicker/214b8e7e-8027-4778-95d5-281c4a8bf356.jpg'
```

I have no idea how to resolve this error

plz answer me. How to upload image in django with proper way using react native

Comment: What is the output of `print(data)`?

Comment: it is a dictionary of all data which is  I sent from the front-end.

Comment: Can you add the output to your question? Also what is the result of `print(request.content_type)`?

Comment: output of  ```print(data)``` is ```{'id': 1646619406851, 'description': 'World', 'title': 'Hello', 'image': 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540m.arshad5857%252FManagPatients/ImagePicker/771703e3-587a-4f53-8e1b-e96ba0a87c49.jpg'}
```

Comment: output for ```print(request.content_type)``` is ```application/json```